# Como saber si un modelo tiene 0 relaciones. Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

tengo un pregunta sobre como optimizar una consulta, lo estoy haciendo con un select a una consulta de active record. Como podría hacer esto en una sola consulta de SQL.

Aqui por ejemplo, es una solicitud.
maintenance_service_requests tiene un Has and belong to many con billing_documents, donde billing_documents tiene un sender_id.
Lo que hago es obtener las solicitudes de mantenimiento que aun no tiene su billing_document con un sender_id especifico.

Asi ahora me funciona, pero se que existe alguna forma de hacerlo solo con activeRecord.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes un `join(:some_model)`, puedes agregar un where de esta forma: `join(:some_model).where(some_model: { attr1: ..., attr2: ... })` para filtrar según attributos de la tabla con la que estás haciendo el join.

Así que en tu caso, esto sería de la siguiente manera:

```
msrs_no_have_billings = maintenance_service_requests.includes(:billing_documents).where(billing_documents: { sender_id: billing_identifier.id })
```

Así te queda en 1 consulta.

Comment: Si, funciona pero eso me devuelve maintenance_service_requests, yo quiero que el has_many sabes cuantos billing_documents hay, no lo maintenance_service_requests